# Respond to or suppress word mail merge prompts with access vba

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, vba, ms-access-2013, word-2013

I am running Office 2013. My Access database has many tables which are linked via ODBC to an Oracle database. I have an Access module which executes a parameter query, exports the results to an Excel spreadsheet, and opens an existing Word merge letter with the spreadsheet set as the merge data source. Further, in the interests of cleaning up after myself and also to avoid potential multi-user conflict, each time the spreadsheet is created it is assigned a unique name and is deleted once the merge is completed. This process works successfully each time I run it BUT each time I run it I receive a number of prompts from Word that I do not know how to handle programatically so that the users will not have to click through these prompts each time they run this module. That's what I need help with.

Here is my code (sorry if it's too long, first time poster). The prompts I need to resolve are listed after the code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Const sPath = "\\MyNetworkPath\Development\"       'development path
'Private Const sPath = "\\MyNetworkPath\"                  'production path

Public Sub RunMailMerge(dataFile As String, mergeFile As String)
On Error GoTo Sub_Error

    Dim sMergeFile As String
    Dim sDataFile As String
    Dim objWordDoc As Word.Document

    sDataFile = dataFile
    sMergeFile = mergeFile

    On Error GoTo Sub_Error
    Set objWordDoc = GetObject(sMergeFile, "Word.Document")

    objWordDoc.Application.Visible = True

    objWordDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _
        Name:=sDataFile, ConfirmConversions:=False, _
        ReadOnly:=False, LinkToSource:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
        PasswordDocument:="", PasswordTemplate:="", WritePasswordDocument:="", _
        WritePasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
        Connection:="", SQLStatement:="", SQLStatement1:=""

    objWordDoc.MailMerge.Destination = wdSendToNewDocument

    objWordDoc.MailMerge.Execute

Sub_Exit:
On Error Resume Next
    ' save and close the merge template
    objWordDoc.Save
    objWordDoc.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
    Set objWordDoc = Nothing
    ' clean up the merge data file
    AttemptToDeleteFile (sDataFile)

    Exit Sub

Sub_Error:
    If Err.Number = 432 Then
        MsgBox "ERROR: Invalid filename provided: '" & sDataFile & "' or " & _
        "'" & sMergeFile & "'."
    Else
        MsgBox Err.Description
    End If

    Resume Sub_Exit

End Sub

'attempt to delete the mailmerge data file
Private Sub AttemptToDeleteFile(strFilename As String)
On Error GoTo Sub_Error

    Kill strFilename

Sub_Exit:
    Exit Sub

Sub_Error:
    If Err.Number = 53 Then 'err 53 = file not found, that means the file is already deleted!
        'no error, continue
        Resume Sub_Exit
    ElseIf MsgBox("Cannot delete file.  Close all Word mailmerge documents and click Retry.", vbRetryCancel + vbExclamation, "File In Use") = vbRetry Then
        Resume
    Else
        On Error GoTo 0
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1024 + 1, "file in use", "File In Use@" & _
                    "Cannot complete the mailmerge process because the file '" & strFilename & "' " & _
                    "is in use.  Close all Word mailmerge documents and try again."
    End If

End Sub

Function OpenProjectAknowledgementLetter()
On Error GoTo OpenProjectAknowledgementLetter_Err

    Dim sDataFile As String
    Dim sMergeFile As String

    sDataFile = sPath & "Acknowledgement\ProjAckgtLtr_" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmddhhnnss") & ".xls"
    sMergeFile = sPath & "Acknowledgement\Acknowledgement_Merge_Letter.docx"

    Debug.Print "Data file: " & sDataFile
    'Debug.Print "Merge file: " & sMergeFile

    ' run the query and populate the data file for the merge letter
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "qselProjectAknowledgementLetter", "Excel97-Excel2003Workbook(*.xls)", sDataFile, False, "", , acExportQualityPrint

    Call RunMailMerge(sDataFile, sMergeFile)

OpenProjectAknowledgementLetter_Exit:
    Exit Function

OpenProjectAknowledgementLetter_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume OpenProjectAknowledgementLetter_Exit

End Function
```

Word prompts that need to be handled:

> Opening this document will run the following SQL command: [select
>   statement]. Data from you database will be placed in the document. Do
>   you want to continue? Yes/No

Selecting Yes produces the following message:

> Sorry, we couldn't find [previously used data source file name]. Is it
>   possible it was moved, renamed or deleted? OK

Clicking OK produces a file open dialog box to Select Data Source. Clicking Cancel on this dialog returns to the merge document which then displays a Select Table prompt with the sheet name selected.

Clicking OK on this prompt allows the code module to proceed without further prompts. The letter is merged to new document, the merge document is saved and closed and the data source file is deleted.

So clearly, Word is accepting the newly assigned data source file and completing the merge successfully. How do I tell Word to skip all of these prompts and just get on with it?

Comment: I think I have solved this as well as it can be solved for the moment. I am still getting one dialog prompt but that is a huge improvement. The solution seemed to be to set the merge file document type to wdNotAMergeDocument when closing it so that the data file link is stripped from it. On opening the merge file set its document type to wdFormLetters and proceed as usual.

Comment: I got the idea to try this from [this  comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21985553/3850246) on another question.